# Watch WWDC videos on Apple TV (4th gen)

Tags: appletv

On the 4th generation of Apple TV, is there a way to watch the presentations delivered at the annual Apple World Wide Developer Conference?

The videos can be viewed on a Mac and on iOS devices. But for some geeks like me, lounging on the couch while watching WWDC vids on the big screen would be considered fun.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a paid developer account for AppleTV you can download, compile and install [WWDC-tvOS](https://github.com/insidegui/WWDC-tvOS). You can also download the OSX version (via the same link) and use Airplay to show the videos on your AppleTV.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Apple Developer](https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-developer/id640199958?platform=appleTV) app.

It's free, and it allows you to stream all of the videos available on [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) (including WWDC14 and later videos) directly to your Apple TV (requires tvOS 15.4 or higher).

[image: Screenshot from https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-developer/id640199958?platform=appleTV taken on Apple TV showing an example video with the 'Watch Now' button]